# Java (netbeans)Why does this give me an illegal start of type?

Tags: java, netbeans

Brand new to Java netbeans)
Why does this give me an illegal start of type?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package doccentertestingencryption;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author dbarry
 */
public class FileLoader {
    public class ClassLoaderDemo {

        String Foo = "bar";
        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoaderDemo.class.getClassLoader();
            if (classLoader != null) {
                InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("mesh.xml");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String s = "";
                try {
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FileLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You've tried to include a `try` statement directly within a class declaration. You can't do that - it's got to be in a method, initializer, constructor or finalizer.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet - getting late...